# How to delete Clipboard.js click event

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I wanted to remove click event on Element in Clipboard.js.
Is there any way to remove click event on button copy icon?

Comment: Could you please post code relevant to your problem? What have you tried to do so far? Are there any console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. If you are working with single page apps, you may want to manage the lifecycle of the DOM more precisely. Here's how you clean up the events and objects that we create.

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

clipboard.destroy();
```